# Nested foreach in knockout.js data show up but not displaying right

Tags: javascript, foreach, knockout.js

I want to display my data from ajax result in the table using knockout. The data show up, but not displaying right. I don't know how to fix that. I've read most of the post here but still cant find what's wrong.

Expected Result

Account A
Header
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3

Displayed Result

Account A
Header
Row 1 Row 2 Row 3

HTML is:

```
<form>
//detail form here
<button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.getReport">GET DATA</button>
</form>

<table data-bind="foreach: coas" style="width: 100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th colspan="5"><span data-bind="text: coaname">COA NAME</span></th></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 20%">date</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">account</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">debet</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">credit</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">saldo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-bind="foreach: coaDetails">
                        <td data-bind="text: date">### date ###</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: coa">### account ###</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: debet">### debet ###</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: credit">### credit ###</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: saldo">### saldo ###</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

JS is:

```
function AddCoaDetails(date,coa,debet,credit,saldo){
        var self= this; 
        self.date = ko.observable(date);
        self.coa = ko.observable(coa);
        if(debet == 0)
            self.debet = '';
        else
            self.debet = ko.observable(addPeriod(debet,","));
        if(credit == 0)
            self.credit = '';
        else
            self.credit = ko.observable(addPeriod(credit,","));
        if(saldo == 0)
            self.saldo = '';
        else
            self.saldo = ko.observable(addPeriod(saldo,","));
    }

    function AddCoaModel(coaname,detail){
        var self = this;
        self.coaname = ko.observable(coaname);
        self.coaDetails = ko.observableArray(detail)
    }

function LedgerModel(){
        var self = this;
        self.coas = ko.observableArray([]);
        var coas = self.coas;

        self.getReport = function(){
            $.ajax({ 
                 //after ajax succeed, will get var listcoa, data sample is attached below
                 var mappedCoas = listcoa.map(function (i) {
                            var coadetail = $(i.detail).each(function(key,item) {
                                                return new AddCoaDetails(item.date, item.coa, item.debet, item.credit, item.saldo);
                                            });
                            return new AddCoaModel(i.namecoa, coadetail);
                        });
                        coas(mappedCoas);
}}

 ko.applyBindings(new LedgerModel());
```

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "namecoa": "PIUTANG",
    "detail": [
      {
        "date": "",
        "coa": "Saldo Awal",
        "debet": 0,
        "credit": 0,
        "saldo": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-10-12",
        "coa": "KAS",
        "debet": "1000000.00",
        "credit": "0.00",
        "saldo": 1000000
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-10-13",
        "coa": "KAS",
        "debet": "10000.00",
        "credit": "0.00",
        "saldo": 1010000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "namecoa": "OPERATIONAL COST",
    "detail": [
      {
        "date": "",
        "coa": "Initial Saldo",
        "debet": 0,
        "credit": 0,
        "saldo": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-10-19",
        "coa": "BANK 2",
        "debet": "0.00",
        "credit": "5000000.00",
        "saldo": -5000000
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-10-19",
        "coa": "BANK 1",
        "debet": "0.00",
        "credit": "10000000.00",
        "saldo": -15000000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is move the foreach from the `<tr>` to the `<tbody>` because the foreach uses the the child elements of the element where it is declared as the template to dupilcate.

```
<table data-bind="foreach: coas" style="width: 100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th colspan="5"><span data-bind="text: coaname">COA NAME</span></th></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 20%">date</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">account</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">debet</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">credit</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">saldo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: coaDetails">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: date">### date ###</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: coa">### account ###</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: debet">### debet ###</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: credit">### credit ###</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: saldo">### saldo ###</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```